# ошибка :бинарный "==": не найден оператор

Tags: c++

Писала программу для сложения/ вычитания/умножения матриц в которые надо было посылать разные типы. Для int все работало float, но надо было ее добавить тип простая дробь. 
В Неader.h не могу понять как реализовать перегрузку оператора "==", когда правый операнд число.
Еще есть проблема с оператора %. Я его перегрузила, но не могу понять как его реализовать с float.

Буду благодарна за помощь. 
P.S. знаю, русские названия переменным лучше не давать

Header.h

```
#ifndef Array_h
#define Array_h

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


template<typename T> class arrr
{

    template <typename T>
    friend arrr<T> operator+ (arrr<T> &m1, arrr<T> &m2);
    template <typename T>
    friend arrr<T> operator- (arrr<T> &m1, arrr<T> &m2);
    template <typename T>
    friend arrr<T> operator* (arrr<T> &m1, arrr<T> &m2);


    friend istream &operator>>(istream &istr, arrr &k)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<k.n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j<k.m; j++)
                istr >> k(i, j);
        return(istr);
    }

    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &ostr, arrr &k)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i<k.n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j<k.m; j++)
                ostr << k(i, j) << "\t";
            ostr << "\n";
        }
        return(ostr);
    }

private:
    int n, m;
    T **value;
public:

    T & operator()(int n, int m);

    arrr(int no, int mo) {
        n = no;
        m = mo;
        value = new T *[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            value[i] = new T[m];
    }

    arrr()
    {
        n = 0;
        m = 0;
    }

    class error {};

    const arrr& operator= (const arrr& a)
    {
        if (&a != this)
        {
            if (value)
            delete (value);

            n = a.n;
            m = a.m;
            value = new T*[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                value[i] = new T[m];
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
                {
                    value[i][j] = a.value[i][j];
                }
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }


    bool operator == (const arrr& a) const
    {
        if (&a == this)
            return true;
        if (n != a.n && m != a.m)
            return false;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                if (value[i][j] != a.value[i][j])
                    return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }


};


template <typename T> arrr<T> operator+(arrr<T>& m1, arrr<T>& m2)
{
    if (m1.n == m2.n && m1.m == m2.m)
    {
        arrr<T> temp(m1.n, m1.m);
        for (int i = 0; i < m1.n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < m1.m; j++)
                temp(i, j) = m1(i, j) + m2(i, j);
        return(temp);
    }
    else throw arrr<T>::error();
}

template <typename T> arrr<T> operator-(arrr<T>& m1, arrr<T>& m2)
{
    if (m1.n == m2.n && m1.m == m2.m)
    {
        arrr<T> temp(m1.n, m1.m);
        for (int i = 0; i < m1.n; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < m1.m; j++)
                temp(i, j) = m1(i, j) - m2(i, j);
        return(temp);
    }
    else throw arrr<T>::error();
}

template <typename T> arrr<T> operator*(arrr<T>& m1, arrr<T>& m2)
{
    if (m1.n == m2.m)
    {
        arrr<T> temp2(m1.n, m1.m);
        for (int i = 0; i < m1.n; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < m2.m; j++)
            {
                temp2(i, j) = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < m1.m; k++)
                    temp2(i, j) = temp2(i, j) + (m1(i, k) * m2(k, j));
            }
        }
        return(temp2);
    }
    else throw arrr<T>::error();

}


template <typename T> void min(arrr<T>& value, int n, int m)
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    T min = value(i, j);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            if (value(i, j)<min)
            {
                min = value(i, j);
            }
        }
    }
    cout << min << "\t";

}


template <typename T> T& arrr<T>::operator()(int n, int m)
{
    return (value[n][m]);
}

template <typename T> static void parn(arrr<T>& value, int n, int m)
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            T u = value(i, j);
            if ((u % 2) == 0)
            {
                value(i, j) = value(i, j) * 3;

            }
            cout << value(i, j) << "\t";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }

}

#endif
```

Header1.h

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class drobi {

private:
    int chislitel, znamenatel,cell;

public:
    friend bool operator <(drobi&f1, drobi&f2);
    friend bool operator < (drobi&f, int a);
    friend drobi operator %(const drobi &dr, int ymn);
    friend drobi operator*(drobi dr, int z);

    drobi(int chisl, int zn)
    {
        chislitel = chisl;
        znamenatel = zn;
    }
    drobi()
    {
        chislitel = 0;
        znamenatel = 0;
    }

    const drobi& operator=(const drobi&f)
    {
        chislitel = f.chislitel;
        znamenatel = f.znamenatel;
        cell = f.cell;
        return *this;
    }
    const drobi& operator=(int a)
    {
        chislitel = 1;
        znamenatel = 1;
        cell = a;
        return *this;
    }

    void set()
    {
        int NOD = 0;
        if (chislitel>znamenatel) NOD = znamenatel; else NOD = chislitel;
        for (int i = NOD; i>0; i--)
        {
            if ((fmod(chislitel, i) == 0) && (fmod(znamenatel, i) == 0))
            {
                chislitel = chislitel / i;
                znamenatel = znamenatel / i;
            }
        }

    }

    void sett()
    {
        int cell;
        int c = chislitel;
        int z = znamenatel;
        if ((chislitel > znamenatel) && znamenatel != 1)
        {
            cell = c / z;
            c = c % z;
            cout << "OR";
            cout << '\t' << '\t' << '\t';
            cout << cell << " " << c << "/" << z;
        }
        if (znamenatel > chislitel)
        {
            z = z / c;
            c = c / c;
            cout << "OR";
            cout << '\t' << '\t' << '\t';
            cout << c << "/" << z;

        }
        if (znamenatel == 1) {
            cout << "OR";
            cout << '\t' << '\t' << '\t';
            cout << c;
        }

        else cout << " ";
    }

    drobi operator+(drobi dr)
    {
        int ymn;
        if (znamenatel != dr.znamenatel)
        {
            ymn = znamenatel;
            znamenatel = znamenatel * dr.znamenatel;
            chislitel = chislitel * dr.znamenatel;
            dr.chislitel = dr.chislitel*ymn;
            dr.znamenatel = znamenatel;
        }
        int x = chislitel + dr.chislitel;
        return drobi(x, znamenatel);
    }

    drobi operator-(drobi dr)
    {
        int ymn;
        if (znamenatel != dr.znamenatel)
        {
            ymn = znamenatel;
            znamenatel = znamenatel * dr.znamenatel;
            chislitel = chislitel * dr.znamenatel;
            dr.chislitel = dr.chislitel*ymn;
            dr.znamenatel = znamenatel;
        }
        int x = chislitel - dr.chislitel;
        return drobi(x, znamenatel);
    }




    drobi operator*(drobi dr)
    {
        int x = chislitel * dr.chislitel;
        int y = znamenatel * dr.znamenatel;
        return drobi(x, y);
    }


    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const drobi& obj)
    {
        stream << obj.chislitel << "/";
        stream << obj.znamenatel << endl;
        return stream;
    }

    friend istream& operator>>(istream& stream, drobi& obj)
    {
        stream >> obj.chislitel;
        stream >> obj.znamenatel;
        return stream;
    }

};

bool operator <(drobi&f1, drobi&f2)
{
    drobi a = f1;
    drobi b = f2;
    if (a.cell != 0)
    {
        a.chislitel = a.znamenatel*a.cell + a.chislitel;
    }
    if (b.cell != 0)
    {
        b.chislitel = b.znamenatel*b.cell + b.chislitel;
    }
    if (a.znamenatel != b.znamenatel)
    {
        a.chislitel = b.znamenatel*a.chislitel;
        b.chislitel = a.znamenatel*b.chislitel;
    }
    return(a.chislitel < b.chislitel) ? true : false;
}
bool operator < (drobi&f, int a)
{
    if (a == 0) return (f.chislitel < 0 || f.znamenatel < 0) ? true : false;
    return (f.cell < a) ? true : false;
}
drobi operator %(const drobi &dr, int ymn)
{
    if ((dr.chislitel % ymn == 0) && (dr.znamenatel % ymn == 0))
    {
        int x = dr.chislitel;
        int y = dr.znamenatel;
        return drobi(x, y);
    }

}
drobi operator*(drobi dr, int z)
{
    int x = dr.chislitel *z;
    int y = dr.znamenatel;
    return drobi(x, y);
}
```

7.cpp

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "Header.h"
#include "Header1.h"

using namespace std;

void PlayINT(int n, int m, int n1, int m1)
{
    arrr<int> a(n, m);
    arrr<int> b(n1, m1);
    arrr<int> c;
    arrr<int> d;
    arrr<int> z;

    cout << "enter matrix A:\n";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "enter matrix B:\n";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "MIN A: ";
    min(a, n, m);
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "MIN B: ";
    min(b, n1, m1);
    cout << "\n";
    try {
        c = a + b;
        cout << "sum of two matrices A and B :\n" << c;
    }
    catch (arrr<int>::error) {
        cout << "error: the sizes of summable matrices must coincide " << endl;
    }
    try {
        d = a - b;
        cout << "subtraction of two matrices A and B:\n" << d;
    }
    catch (arrr<int>::error)
    {
        cout << "error:the sizes of matrices must coincide" << endl;
    }
    try {
        z = a * b;
        cout << "multiplication of two matrices A and B:\n" << z;
    }
    catch (arrr<int>::error)
    {
        cout << "error: the number of columns of the first matrix must coincide with the number of rows of the second matrix" << endl;
    }
    cout << "All items with paired values are increased three times, matrice A:" << endl;
    parn(a, n, m);
    cout << "All items with paired values are increased three times, matrice B:" << endl;
    parn(b, n1, m1);
}

void PlayDROBI(int n, int m, int n1, int m1)
{
    arrr<drobi> a(n, m);
    arrr<drobi> b(n1, m1);
    arrr<drobi> c;
    arrr<drobi> d;
    arrr<drobi> z;

    cout << "enter matrix A:\n";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "enter matrix B:\n";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "MIN A: ";
    min(a, n, m);
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "MIN B: ";
    min(b, n1, m1);
    cout << "\n";
    try {
        c = a + b;
        cout << "sum of two matrices A and B :\n" << c;
    }
    catch (arrr<drobi>::error) {
        cout << "error: the sizes of summable matrices must coincide " << endl;
    }
    try {
        d = a - b;
        cout << "subtraction of two matrices A and B:\n" << d;
    }
    catch (arrr<drobi>::error)
    {
        cout << "error:the sizes of matrices must coincide" << endl;
    }
    try {
        z = a * b;
        cout << "multiplication of two matrices A and B:\n" << z;
    }
    catch (arrr<drobi>::error)
    {
        cout << "error: the number of columns of the first matrix must coincide with the number of rows of the second matrix" << endl;
    }
    cout << "All items with paired values are increased three times, matrice A:" << endl;
    parn(a, n, m);
    cout << "All items with paired values are increased three times, matrice B:" << endl;
    parn(b, n1, m1);
}
void PlayFloat(int n, int m, int n1, int m1)
{
    arrr<float> a(n, m);
    arrr<float> b(n1, m1);
    arrr<float> c;
    arrr<float> d;
    arrr<float> z;

    cout << "enter matrix A:\n";
    cin >> a;
    cout << "enter matrix B:\n";
    cin >> b;
    cout << "MIN A: ";
    min(a, n, m);
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "MIN B: ";
    min(b, n1, m1);
    cout << "\n";
    try {
        c = a + b;
        cout << "sum of two matrices A and B :\n" << c;
    }
    catch (arrr<float>::error) {
        cout << "error: the sizes of summable matrices must coincide " << endl;
    }
    try {
        d = a - b;
        cout << "subtraction of two matrices A and B:\n" << d;
    }
    catch (arrr<float>::error)
    {
        cout << "error:the sizes of matrices must coincide" << endl;
    }
    try {
        z = a * b;
        cout << "multiplication of two matrices A and B:\n" << z;
    }
    catch (arrr<float>::error)
    {
        cout << "error: the number of columns of the first matrix must coincide with the number of rows of the second matrix" << endl;
    }
    cout << "All items with paired values are increased three times, matrice A:" << endl;
    parn(a, n, m);
    cout << "All items with paired values are increased three times, matrice B:" << endl;
    parn(b, n1, m1);
}


int main()
{
    int n, m, n1, m1, ch, y = 0;
    cout << "enter number of rows and columns of matrice A: ";
    cin >> m >> n;
    cout << "enter number of rows and columns of matrice B: ";
    cin >> m1 >> n1;

    do {

        cout << "\n 1.INT";
        cout << "\n 2.FLOAT";
        cout << "\n 3.DROBI";
        cout << "\n 4.Exit ";
        cout << "\nEnter Your Choice: ";
        cin >> ch;
        switch (ch)
        {
        case 1:PlayINT(n, m, n1, m1);
            break;
        case 2: PlayFloat(n, m, n1, m1);
            break;
        case 3: PlayDROBI(n, m, n1, m1);
            break;
        case 4:y = 1;
            break;
        }

    } while (y != 1);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Я говорю про перегрузку "==" для варианта этой строчки
if ((u % 2) == 0)

Comment: Как сложно читается. У оператора `%` тип возвращаемого значения - `drobi`, у которого нет оператора сравнения с int. А ещё некоторые операторы в шаблоне `arrr`у вас приватные, так и задумывалось ?

Comment: Проблема % в том, что он не моет вообще работать с чем-то кроме int. Для float существует fmod.

Comment: В private то я случайно не туда засунула. Если в public его переместить, то ничего не поменяется.

Comment: Да почему не может ? Вот [пример](https://pastebin.mozilla.org/9080336)

Comment: даже если и так, но у меня оно почему-то не работает

Comment: Можете привести минимальный пример, воспроизводящий проблему ? У вас слишком много кода в вопросе.
@Brambuca

Comment: Когда я компилирую программу, то появляются 2 ошибки, которые показывают на одно и то же место.

Comment: if ((u % 2) == 0) это из Header.h и вы дает ошибки:Ошибка C2678 бинарный "==": не найден оператор, принимающий левый операнд типа "drobi" (или приемлемое преобразование отсутствует)б и вторая ошибка: Ошибка C2296 %: недопустимо, левый операнд имеет тип "float"

Comment: Таки осилил (читал `Header1.h` вместо `Header.h`). В одном случае вы пытаетесь для float вызвать оператор % - так нельзя, во втором у вас в классе `drobi` не определён оператор `bool operator==(int i) const;` Для `float` нужно отдельно специализация шаблона писать (и для double), чтобы вместо % использовать `modf` или что там у вас в логике, а в `drobi` просто добавьте оператор `==` Ну либо сделайте обёртку над `float` и `double` (`MyDouble`, со всеми необходимыми вам операторами) и уже с ней работайте вместо встроенных `float` и `double` @Brambuca

Comment: для == я вроде написала

Comment: bool operator == (int x) {
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) {
                    if (value[i][j] != x)
                        return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
    }

Comment: но я не могу понять куда его поставить. Если в Нeader, то ошибка остается

Comment: "Для float нужно отдельно специализация шаблона писать (и для double), чтобы вместо % использовать modf" в этом и есть самый большой вопрос. Про fmod я догадалась, но мне не понятно как это реализовать, чтобы при float оно перескакивало

Comment: В классе `drobi` не оператора `==`. Нету. Отсутствует. Совсем. В том коде который указан в вопросе оператор сравнения есть только в шаблоне arrr. Про специализацию я чуть позже нагуглю, я не то чтобы спец большой по шаблонам

Comment: В классе дроби мне нужен опиратор  == сравнения с числом. Я как-то не оч пойму его реализацию. Для arrr я представляю, а для drobi пока не соображу.

Comment: Я ещё не пробовала, но возможно можно так сделать для %. Для вещественных типов будет вызываться второй вариант, для остальных - первый
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<!std::is_floating_point<T>::value, bool>::type
isEven(T &t)
{
    return t % 2 == 0;
}
template<class T>
typename std::enable_if<is_floating_point<T>::value, bool>::type
isEven(T &t)
{
    return fmod(t, static_cast<T>(2)) == 0;
}

Comment: Дробь - это число (4/2 - это 2), просто сравните его с числом и всё. Только наверное лучше сравнивать с double, используя некоторую EPS (`bool equal = std::abs(A-B) < EPS?true:false;` где `EPS=1e-9`, к примеру

Comment: Да проще без всяких `enableIf` сделать специализацию под `float` и `double` наверное. Не знаю. Пришёл бы уже кто-нибудь опытный и нормально ответил